# MySQL: Joining table duplicates SUM()

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum, left-join

I am working with a bilingual website that deals with products.

Each product has a `sku` and `supplier_id`. When inserting products, if the `sku` **and** `supplier_id` already exists, instead of creating a new product, I simply update its quantities.

If only the `sku` matches, but the `supplier_id` is different, then I create a new product.

Because the website is multi language, there are some tables for translations.

When I search products I display one for each `sku`, summing the quantities.

This is my query

```
SELECT
    products.id, products.sku, products.slug,
    SUM(products.quantity) quantity,
    suppliers.name supplier_name,
    locale.description,
    categories.name category_name
FROM products products
    LEFT JOIN products_locale locale ON (products.id = locale.product_id AND locale.language_code = 'it')
    LEFT JOIN app_suppliers suppliers ON products.supplier_id = suppliers.id
    LEFT JOIN app_categories_locale categories ON (products.category_id = categories.category_id AND categories.language_code = 'it')
WHERE products.slug = 'slug'
GROUP BY products.sku
```

There are 2 different products with the same `sku`, one has quantity 5 and the other has 2.

The `quantity` field should return 7, instead it returns 9. Basically, the second product is duplicated.

Removing the `LEFT JOIN products_locale locale ON (products.id = locale.product_id AND locale.language_code = 'it')` solves the problem, but I need that field.

What is more strange is that I join two translation tables, `products_locale` and `app_categories_locale`, but only `products_locale` causes this behavior.

Is there any way of retrieving the same fields without duplicating the rows ?

Thank you

Comment: It's really hard to say without any other data. Try selecting * and removing the group. This should reveal all the rows and some columns which are duplicating lines. Once you identify those, it'll be easy to update the query

Comment: What else you would like to know ? Removing the group changes nothing and selecting * also changes nothing. As I said, that single LEFT JOIN is the problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you really need to read products.slug, when you have WHERE condition products.slug='slug'? I mean, you anyway can only get rows with value 'slug'.
2. Your product table may look like

   ```
   ID | quantity | products.sku | ...
   ----------------------------------
    1 |   5      |     sku1
    2 |   2      |     sku1
    ...
   ```

   and products_locale may look like

   ```
   product_id | description | language_code | ...
   -------------------------------------
       1      |   abc       |      it
       2      |   def       |      it
       2      |   xyz       |      it
    ...
   ```

   The issue is, that you first create a cartesian product of those relations, which results to
   following view:

   ```
   ID | quantity | products.sku | product_id | description | language_code | ...
   -----------------------------------------------------------
    1 |   5      |     sku1     |     1      |   abc       |      it
    2 |   2      |     sku1     |     2      |   def       |      it
    2 |   2      |     sku1     |     2      |   xyz       |      it
   ```

   Now you group this cartesian product and compute the sum. You must know, if it is correct,
   that one product has more than one description in one language. It may be wrong from the 
   business view of your application. In that case, you only need to "repair" your database.

   If your data are correct, then you need to group `products` separately. Something like:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM
       (SELECT id, sku, SUM(quantity) from products WHERE slug='slug' group by sku, id) p 
       LEFT JOIN products_locale l ON p.id=l.product_id     
       LEFT JOIN ...
       LEFT JOIN ...
   ```

   But then, and also using the sql from viki888, you will get 2 rows in the result of the same sku, however, with
   the correct sum 7, and with different descriptions.
3. I wonder, if your select even runs, because when grouping, you can select only attributes, you are grouping by (plus the aggregate functions on the remaining attributes). Since you group by `sku` , in 1 group of the same `sku` value, you get several products. Therefore, even if you had only one description of each product (in 1 language), you are trying to attach to group of products one description, but which one? It makes no sence, and also the sql should crash on executing.

try to summarize, what's you aim to do, and give some sample data (content of `products_locale` , content of `products` and your desired result)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
SELECT P.*, locale.description
FROM (    
    SELECT
        products.id, products.sku, products.slug,
        SUM(products.quantity) quantity,
        suppliers.name supplier_name,
        categories.name category_name
    FROM products products
        LEFT JOIN app_suppliers suppliers ON products.supplier_id = suppliers.id
        LEFT JOIN app_categories_locale categories ON (products.category_id = categories.category_id AND categories.language_code = 'it')
    WHERE products.slug = 'slug'
    GROUP BY products.sku) P        
    LEFT JOIN products_locale locale ON (P.id = locale.product_id AND locale.language_code = 'it')
```

Hope this should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but this query has something wrong in the Syntax

Comment: What is the issue thrown?